# python 2.7.6 isupper function in if/elif/else statements

Tags: python-2.7

I need help with the str.isupper() function. I am trying to use it in an if/elif/else statement. The program is this.

```
String = raw_input( 'Please enter a string. ')
if String[:1].isupper():
    print 'The first character,' + string[0] ('is capitalized')
```

I am trying to make it so if you enter a capital it will print one thing and if it is not capitalized it will print something else. How would i do this?

Edit: I guess I don't understand how to make the program print the two situations. I get if/elif/else statements, but i don't understand them with the isupper() function. Please explain.

Comment: And you are getting an error saying that a string is not callable?

Comment: no it is just not working for some reason

Answer (score 1):

The print statement required two minor corrections:

```
String = raw_input( 'Please enter a string. ')
if String[:1].isupper():
    print 'The first character,' + String[0] + ', is capitalized'
```

The first was that `String` needed to be capitalized. and the second was to remove the parentheses.

**MORE:**  Here is the code with a working if/else statement to show both cases:

```
String = raw_input( 'Please enter a string. ')
if String[:1].isupper():
    print 'The first character, ' + String[0] + ', is capitalized'
else:
    print 'The first character, ' + String[0] + ', is not capitalized'
```

Comment: @jak10101 Please check to see that your code has the second `+` in the print statement.